# How to add picture to tooltip PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

> `<i [pTooltip]="picture" tooltipPosition="bottom" class="pi pi-images"></i> <ng-template #picture> <img src="" alt="here img"> </ng-template>`

Error Type 'TemplateRef' is not assignable to type 'string'

Is there a way to add a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<i
pTooltip="<img class='cell-view-file__tooltip' src='{{cell.value}}' alt='{{fileName}}'/>"
[escape]="false"
appendTo="body"
class="pi pi-images"
tooltipPosition="bottom"
tooltipStyleClass="tooltip"
```

> 

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is a discussed topic on GitHub. So at least currently template is not supported for tooltip. But I found this **[comment](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3496#issuecomment-520825549)**: which says:

> Set escape to `false`, and it will render html:
>
> `<div pTooltip="Some text <br> next line" tooltipPosition="top" [escape]="false"></div>`

This seems to work fine with this sample I tried:

```
<p pTooltip="<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/100/200' />" [escape]="false">Hover me!</p>
```

**[DEMO STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tooltip-demo-wsvvwh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Can you tell me how to change the style of this HTML element?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, seems like there is `tooltipStyleClass` where you can define your own styles. Check documentation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tooltip

Comment: Thanks. I did that and it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, not that familiar with Primeng, but sounds to me that you perhaps need to use `::ng-deep .target-class-here {.....styles here....}` If that doesn't work, I would suggest to open a new question for that.

Comment: Yesterday I solved this problem in two ways.
HTML attributes width and height. And through :: ng-deep. Thanks for the help.